# Function definition in a template class

Tags: c++, templates

Usually, one declares a member function in a header file and uses a source file to implement it. My understanding of the reason is that the function implementation will reside in only one translation unit and will be just linked to other units (no duplicate code), and it also allows separation of the interface and implementation, and removes the need to forward declare functions that depend on each other.

However, member functions in a template depend on the template arguments, which couldn't be known if the implementation was placed in a source file. However, it is still possible to define such functions outside the class, but the major argument for it doesn't apply anymore.

So, which is better?

```
template <class T>
class A
{
    T m()
    {
        return T();
    }
};
```

or

```
template <class T>
class A
{
    T m();
};

template <class T>
T A::m()
{
    return T();
}
```

These two pieces of code would be equivalent if it was `inline T A::m()`, but is there any difference without it? What if the function is virtual? Is it just a matter of coding style, or does it have different semantics? If the function is large enough, will it prevent duplicate code, or is the compiler smart enough not to inline it if it won't bring any benefits?

Comment: The `inline` keyword isn't necessary for class member functions. Template or not.

Comment: @user9212993 I am not implying it is.

Comment: So why do you mention it at all then?

Comment: @user9212993 - It is necessary for non-templated classes if you provide an out of class inline definition, in the same header.

Comment: @StoryTeller Not necessary in the *same* header though, it can be written in separate header. But everything will be fine as long as both headers are properly included.

Comment: @VTT - It has nothing to do with separation to headers, but with ODR violations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> These two pieces of code would be equivalent if it was `inline T A::m()`, but is there any difference without it?

Not for templates, the member functions are implicitly `inline`, for both inside and outside the class definitions.

> What if the function is virtual?

Makes no difference.

> Is it just a matter of coding style, or does it have different semantics?

Mostly stylistic. However, it affects how name lookup works. So if we were to modify the class definition a bit

```
template <class T>
class A
{
    using foo = T;
    foo m();
};
```

We would not be able to define the member outside as

```
template <class T>
foo A<T>::m()
{
    return T();
}
```

Since the lookup for `foo` doesn't happen inside the class definition until after the qualification `A<T>::`. We'd need to either fully qualify `foo` itself, like so `typename A<T>::foo`. Or perhaps use a trailing return type.

> If the function is large enough, will it prevent duplicate code, or is the compiler smart enough not to inline it if it won't bring any benefits?

Neither style should have either an adverse of positive effect on it. Both are subject to quality of implementation issues. But of course, different implementations may have different qualities.